# I cant update the variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a code. First, I think what it was very simple, but not to me.

I can't update the variable. I know why I can't update. But how can I solve this problem? I need what var "sum" equal 7.

```
<p id="demo">DEMO</p>

<script>
var number1 = 5;
var number2 = 0;

var p = document.createElement("p");
var sum = document.createTextNode("sum = " + (number1 + number2).toFixed());

var number2 = 2; /*It is possible somehow update a variable "sum", which can equal after "var number2 = 2;" not 5 and update to 7? The var "sum" must updates to 7. 

HOW CAN REALIZE THAT IDEA??? OR what advice or solve you can give to me?
*/
p.appendChild(sum);
demo.appendChild(p);
</script>

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrpuro23/2/
```

Comment: You should put it in corresponding tag! put it under javascript at least as you code using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you append your element, you can't access it contents anymore.
So what I did was creating a reference directly to the inserted element and edit it's content.

I also did make a little function, so you don't have this code twice.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("result");
var number1 = 5;
var number2 = 0;

printResult();

var number2 = 2; 
printResult();

function printResult() {
  container.innerHTML = "sum = " + (number1 + number2).toFixed();
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

var sum is textnode for a document, the result of number1+number2 has been evaluated and type-casted into string and therefore updating number2 gives no impact to sum
even if you code like this you can't change the value of sum as it was computed before and will be the same until you explicitly make changes to sum

```
var number1 = 5;
var number2 = 2;
var sum = number1 + number2;
var number2 = 4; //the sum will still has value of 7
```

Comment: I need a SOLVE how to do what "sum" CAN equal 7. I dont know to much about JS, but help. I see many times on sites, when i change one parameter of amount, and all amount changes with a new parameter. Like in internet-shops.